# Error 255 when installing openSSL from source

Tags: make, install-from-source, openssl

I need to build openssl from source because it's needed to build a mysql driver for android for Qt but when I do "make install" I get the following error:

```
cms.pod around line 457: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 461: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 465: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 470: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255
```

Any help?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04(clean install).

Here is the tutorial I am using: [link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Qt5_mysql_plugin_for_Android)

The build was done using:

```
RANLIB="$BR"ranlib CC="$BR"gcc ./Configure android-armv7 --prefix=$SR/usr
ANDROID_DEV=$SR/usr make
make install
```

Comment: I also have this problem with 1.01m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly 2 years later and this question is not closed! I had the exact problem.

Changing

> make install

to

> make install_sw

will install OpenSSL without the man pages, thus alleviating this issue. The man pages are not required.

Here is the source:
https://github.com/shadow/shadow/issues/206